# Solve differential equation in physics context: $y'' = -b\,y'+g$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working through Schaum's outline Physics book, and I don't really understand one task in it. It's about solving this ODE that comes up in a free fall with air resistance. I don't want to bother you with the physics too much, rather with the method of how it's been solved. Granted I've forgot most of the techniques, but first of I'd write:

$y''+b\,y' = g$

then forming the characteristic polynomial:

$p(\lambda) = \lambda^2+b\,\lambda \quad \Rightarrow \lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = -b$

In my sight I'm done right there:

$y = c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot e^{-b\cdot t}$

However this doesn't seem to be the solution: $y = k(e^{-b\,t}-1)+(\frac{g}{b})\,t$

Did I miss an Ansatz?

Comment: Is it $b \color{red}{y}$ as in the post or $b \color{blue}{y'}$ as in the title? If it is the latter, then you found the homogeneous solution $y_{h}$, but not the particular solution. Assuming $g$ is constant, the ansatz $y_{p} = g/b$ solves the equation and so $y = y_{h} + y_{p}$. Else, use an integrating factor $$y'' + by' = g \implies (\exp(Bt)y')' = \exp(Bt)g \implies y' = C\exp(-Bt) + \exp(-Bt) \int g \exp(Bt) dt$$ where $B' = b$, then integrate again.

Comment: Yes, I think it was meant to be velocity @mattos

Comment: I thought g is a constant and not of interest. I partly understand the solution now whatsoever except of: why $b$ also is dependent on $t$ and specifically in your solution how you're using $\exp(b')$. Sorry, I just learned solving these by formula and not intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t incorporated $\color{green} g$ in your solution, but it appears in the ODE. To solve it, you may substitute $u =y’$ to get $$u’=g -bu $$ This is separable: $$\frac{du}{g-bu} =dt \\ -\ln|g-bu| = bt + A\\ bu-g =Be^{-bt} \\ bdy = (Be^{-bt} +g)dt \\ by =-\frac{B}{b} e^{-bt} +gt +C $$

Comment: Thank you, this seems crystal-clear. Just in the the second last line: you mean $dt$ on the right side?

Comment: @Leon Yes, that’s was a typo.